# Add bootstrap icon to button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following code which have button with text inside,
I want to add to the button also icon from bootstrap (in the left side of the text ) how should I do that ?

The icon is  **glyphicon glyphicon-plus**

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("New", "Create",
        null new { @class = "Button", @style = "float:right" })
    </p>    
</div> 
<br />
<style type="text/css">
        .CreateButton {
            background: blue
;
            color: white;
            padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
            height: 30px;
            width: 60px;
        }


    </style>
<br />
```

Comment: this doesn't look very complete. what's with this class on the top of the code?

Comment: @StenPelzer-I've update the post please check and let me know if someting missing...

Comment: The code you've posted is not html. What is it?

Comment: @omeinusch-its razor which you can use in ASP.Net MVC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't really allow me to help you any better, but let's try.

You need to copy all properties of `.glyphicon` class inside `.CreateButton:before {}` and add - also there - `content` property with value of the icon you want to insert. Check [glyphicons stylsheet](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss) to find out code of the icon you want. The plus sign you're searching for has a value of "\2b".

```
.CreateButton:before {
    // the part that will be different for each icon
    content: "\e001";
    // copied from .glyphicon class
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Since this is the accepted answer, I'll add that in some circumstances it might be better to use the answer by user **cache**.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,how you get the content: "\e001"; and how should I put the glyphicon glyphicon-plus?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a button tag instead of input

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Sign in
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

use this to insert the icon

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
```

UPDATE :
By using the  tag , you are automatically inserting the icon in html. For more info look at this [GLYPHICONS - bootstrap icon font hex value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740700/glyphicons-bootstrap-icon-font-hex-value). Also it is better to use the classes.