# How Can I Use CSS :after to Add a Glyphicon Element to an Input

Tags: css, glyphicons

I have an `<input>` element, and I can't modify the HTML around it, but I want to add a glyphicon (`<i class="glyphicons glyphicons-some-icon"/>`) inside of it.  I was hoping to do it with CSS, but I can't seem to get `:after` to work.  I thought something like the following would generate that element:

```
#my-input {
    content: attr(class, 'glyphicons glyphicon-some-icon'); 
    content: '<i/>'; 
}
```

but it doesn't.  Could anyone who understands `:after` better explain how I can generate the desired `<i class="glyphicons glyphicons-some-icon"/>` using `:after`?

Comment: You can't. `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are inserted inside the element. `<input>` elements cannot have children, and therefore cannot have pseduo-element children, unfortunately.

Comment: You can find these by looking at Bootstrap's stylesheet:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740700/glyphicons-bootstrap-icon-font-hex-value

Comment: This isnt possible with pure CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **:before** and **:after** are applied inside a container, which means you can
>   use it for elements with an end tag.[see explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

See below example. to achieve what you want.

**NOTE**: parent position is relative so that chilled absolute position  will take top and bottom depending on parent.

```css
.myInput:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0a9";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 7px;
}
.my{
position:relative
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="my">

  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

</div>
```

OR

```css
.mystyle:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0a9";
}
.myInput {
  position: relative;
}
.myInput div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myInput">
  <input class="mystyle" type="text" value="" />
  <div class="mystyle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could achieve what you are trying to do.

```css
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: icons;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none; /* Not to be trusted, but hey. */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="stats" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#x21dd;">
<input type="text"/>
</h2>
```

OR

```css
.glyphicon-search:before {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
<input type="text"/>
</div>
```