# where is the icon in this bootstrap template?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

where is the icon in this bootstrap template?
demo here: https://genesisui.com/demo/?theme=root&version=angular

screenshot：
the icon is in red box.

[image]

I can not find it in debugging tool,

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740700/glyphicons-bootstrap-icon-font-hex-value show how to use the `::before`

Answer (score 1):

it is on the css, I will include the image for show you where.

[image]

Comment: in that case you need change the image, they are using the following link.

https://thesabbir.github.io/simple-line-icons/

search the image that you need in that case I think that you need the image named "arrow right".you need to change the content for "\e606"

Comment: sorry I don't have the same css that you are changing but you need search a css class similar to this "body:not(.top-nav) .sidebar ul.nav li.nav-item a.nav-link.nav-dropdown-toggle:before " or search the content "\e605" and change that for the \e606

Comment: @Ronald text is much preferred over images in questions and answers.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the recomendation I will take care about that in the future